# Docker image pull error from public registry

Tags: docker

I had a docker desktop installed on Mac OS. Everything was working great until I installed a recent update. Now, getting the following error.

```
> docker pull public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:1.21-alpine
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.
```

I did try after login to docker, I tried restarting, cleanup all docker data, factory reset, Uninstalled and installed a latest version. Nothing works.

However the same command works on different machine.

Comment: Answer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/public-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

Needed to logout from public ecr

```
docker logout public.ecr.aws
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/public-troubleshooting.html